# How to obtain hierarchical relationships for org units based on positions hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table containing some HR data including (amongst other details) the position id, the parent position id, and the org unit id.

Something like

```
pos_id | parent_pos_id | pos_name            | org_id | org_name
   1   |     null      | CEO                 |   A    | Executive
   2   |       1       | Assistant           |   A    | Executive
   3   |       1       | IT Director         |   B    | Information Technology
   4   |       1       | Finances Director   |   C    | Finances
   5   |       3       | Systems Leader      |   B    | Information Technology
   6   |       5       | Database Manager    |   B1   | Database Systems
   7   |       5       | Application Manager |   B2   | OS and Applications
   8   |       4       | Finances Leader     |   C    | Finances
   9   |       4       | Financial Assistant |   C    | Finances
  10   |       8       | Payroll Manager     |   C1   | Payroll
```

and I need to obtain the information of the parent org unit id for each record, based on the position hierarchical relationships.

So, for the above example, the desired output would be:

```
org_id | parent_org_id
   A   |      null
   B   |       A
   C   |       A
  B1   |       B
  B2   |       B
  C1   |       C
```

Is there a query that can be built to obtain this in an SQL Server database?

Comment: You might want to read about [HIERACHYID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-2017)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `self join`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8e5a112606de472b95fdc4cd425bdec4)**

```
select  a.org_id as org_id,b.org_id as parentorgid
from t1 a
left join t1 b on a.parent_pos_id=b.pos_id
where a.org_id<>b.org_id or b.org_id is null
```

OUTPUT:

```
org_id  parentorgid
A   
B         A
C         A
B1        B
B2        B
C1        C
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a Recursive CTE for this,The psuedo code is below

```
with cte as 
(
 select org_id,parentorg_id,pos_id,parentpos_id from hrtable where parentpos_id is null
 UNION ALL
 select org_id,parentorg_id,pos_id,parentpos_idfrom hrtable t join cte c on t.parentpso_id=c.pos_id
)
select org_id,parentorg_id from cte c
```

Comment: Thanks @Zee786. Recursive CTEs are certainly something I should consider when working with trees and hierarchical structures in general. The following query (based on your pseudo query) worked for me: `with CTE AS (
SELECT pos_id,parent_pos_id,org_id,parent_org_id FROM [dbo].[MyTable] WHERE parent_pos_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t.pos_id,t.parent_pos_id,t.org_id,c.org_id parent_org_id FROM [dbo].[MyTable] t INNER JOIN CTE c on c.pos_id = t.parent_pos_id)
SELECT org_id,parent_org_id from CTE where ISNULL(org_id,'X') <> ISNULL(parent_org_id,'X');`.

Comment: Thats Great,Can you mark my solution as answer if it satisfies your problem.